# Multi-robot navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have problem with implementing navigation to work with multiple robots. Errors:

Waiting on transform from /robot_1/base to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Frame id /robot_1/base does not exist!
Waiting on transform from /robot_2/base to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Frame id /robot_2/base does not exist!

Probably, the problem is in transformations that transform /map to /base and not from /map to /robot_1/base. I use groups/namespaces in launch file to separate each robot node with correspondiong move_base node from other nodes. To run navigation stack I launch robot_configuaration.launch and move_base.launch. I have found the following solution:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="robot_1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_1"/>
    <node pkg="usarsim" type="usarsim.py" respawn="false" name="usarsim_1" output="screen">
  </group>
  <group ns="robot_2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_2"/>
    <node pkg="usarsim" type="usarsim2.py" respawn="false" name="usarsim_2" output="screen">
  </group>
```

and

```
<launch>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/user/Desktop/ROS/map.pgm 0.05" respawn="false">
  </node>

  <group ns="robot_1"><br>
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
      <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
      <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
      <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
      <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
      <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" /><br>
    </node><br>
  </group>

  <group ns="robot_2">
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    ...same as for group_1
```

but this doesn't work. Is there some solution to
automatically map all topics and tf's directly from .launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9837/multi-robot-navigation/) by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, it turns out that the python version of transformBroadcaster has a bug in that it doesn't read the `tf_prefix` parameter. I've filed a ticket to have this fixed here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4943.

In the meantime, you have a couple of options:

1. Write the search param logic yourself for the transformBroadcaster, submit a patch to the above ticket, get mad props from the ROS community for fixing a bug :)
2. Have a parameter on your node that allows you to change the frame name before you pass it to the transformBroadcaster.
3. Switch to the C++ API which works as expected.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are missing a couple of remappings and some custom parameter changes... that need to be done. This may not be the complete solution but it should get you a bit closer. Let me know how it goes.

```
<group ns="robot_0">
 <param name="~tf_prefix" value="robot_0" />

 <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base_node" output="screen">
    <remap from="odom" to="odom" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel" />
    <remap from="map" to="/map" />

    <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_2dnav)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" /><br>

    <param name="~/global_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="robot_0/base_link" />
    <param name="~/local_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="robot_0/base_link" />
    <param name="~/local_costmap/global_frame" value="robot_0/odom" />
 </node>
</group>
```

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-30**:
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=DCTZSB2Q I guess something is wrong here... Can you tell me what does tf_prefix do? Isn't that for remapping tf frames (odom->robot_x/odom)?

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-04-29**:
Any chance you can generate a pdf of your TF tree "rosrun tf view_frames" and post the output. Its possible that something could be wrong there.

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-28**:
This problem with /scan was in costmap_common_params.yaml. Now i get no errors, changed ~tf_prefix to tf_prefix, but navigation doesn't give any sign of life, no footprint, no obstacles, no path.. edit: without ~ navigation doesn't subscribe to most of topics, including scan and odom

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-28**:
I figured how to solve this errors - rosmake :) but I had to remove this 3 params change because there weren't any subscriptions for odom and scan in move_base. Still there is one proble left..move_base nodes subscribe to /scan, not on /robot_x/scan? odom si fine.

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-28**:
I get the same warning as above, nothing happens with changing the code with this 3 remappings and this 3 params. Is it needed to  remap from odom to odom?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [navigation_stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_stage) package in the [navigation_tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_tutorials) stack has an example launch file for how to bring the navigation stack up with multiple robots called move_base_multi_robot.launch. Examining that launch file should help you out a bit.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-29**:
Yes, in rviz everything looks ok!

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-04-29**:
Does the navigation_stage launch file work correctly on your system when you try to run it?

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-29**:
Yes, I tried to setup my launch file similar to this navigation_stage .launch, but I don't use fake localization, and stageros node.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the frames you posted, it looks like the driver for your robot is not remapping the frames it is broadcasting when "tf_prefix" is set. Details on the "tf_prefix" parameter and what it does can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions#tf_prefix). How are you publishing the frames for your robot? With a transformBroadcaster? Or some other way?

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-05-03**:
Yes, with transformBroadcaster. The following code is the same for robot_1 and robot_2: broadcaster.sendTransform(position, orientation, rospy.Time.now(), "odom", "map"). Do I need to change odom for every robot_x to /robot_x/odom manually or this is done automatically with tf_prefix?